# Unable To Get Multiple "before" Constraints To Work

Tags: routes, here-api, here-maps-rest

I'm using the FindSequence API with the following waypoints:

```
&destination1=Stop-20712;-33.878683,151.1377808;st:7200;before:destination3;before:destination4
&destination2=Stop-20714;-33.8021024,150.9552574;st:7200;before:destination3;before:destination4
&destination3=Stop-20710;-33.9486425,151.080674;st:7200
&destination4=Stop-20711;-33.8929182,151.0596753;st:7200
```

The goal is to always have destination1 and destination2 as the first waypoints, however it does not appear to work. Here is the result:

```
"results": [
      {
         "waypoints": [
            {
               "id": "start-0",
               "lat": -33.97943,
               "lng": 150.86694,
               "sequence": 0,
               "estimatedArrival": null,
               "estimatedDeparture": "2021-01-06T08:30:00+10:00",
               "fulfilledConstraints": []
            },
            {
               "id": "Stop-20710",
               "lat": -33.948643,
               "lng": 151.08067,
               "sequence": 1,
               "estimatedArrival": "2021-01-06T08:46:32+10:00",
               "estimatedDeparture": "2021-01-06T10:46:32+10:00",
               "fulfilledConstraints": [
                  "st:7200"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id": "Stop-20714",
               "lat": -33.8021,
               "lng": 150.95526,
               "sequence": 2,
               "estimatedArrival": "2021-01-06T11:16:06+10:00",
               "estimatedDeparture": "2021-01-06T13:16:06+10:00",
               "fulfilledConstraints": [
                  "st:7200",
                  "before:destination4"
               ]
            },
```

It appears the waypoint "Stop-20714" has only taken into account a single *before* constraint. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, Here support set me straight. The constraint should actually be comma delimited

```
&destination1=Stop-20712;-33.878683,151.1377808;st:7200;before:destination3,destination4
```

It's all good now.